# How to get a div position after a tab

Tags: jquery, html

I am actually working on a website and i would like to add some changes. I let you know that i am a beginner in coding.

The purpose is to change to background color of a scrolling menu (home, about us, ... on the link to the picture at the bottom) when it is on different parts of the website (black to white, white to black.. ).

Let's strat with part A : I have a kind of a "tab" in the website and you can choose 4 options (test1/2/3/4 on the link to the picture at the bottom). For each option you have 4 packages displayed. 
As you have to choose which option you would like, the 3 others are hidden.

Below this "tab" you have an other part of the website : part B

The scrolling menu is actually displayed in white color when you are in part A, and i would like it to become black when it superimposes part B.

I wanted to do it with Jquery and it worked. The only problem is I set a fixed position for the color changement because I can get the real position of the top of part B. Indeed, I've tried to fix it in many ways, but none worked..

I use Jquery functions as .position(), .offset() ... Each one of them return a wrong position : It returns the position of part B but considering that part A is 4 options, one below the other... 
.offset() on the top of part B will return  2700px (test1 + 2+ +3 +4) , but it should be something like 700px (option test1).

This may not be really clear, the picture below can help you to understand my issue. I can find some codes to help you understand.

Thank you in advance for your consideration !

```html
<div class="wrap medium">
    <div class="left size-3 responsive">
        <h3>
            <a class="txt-sm btn fast" href="#test1" data-ref="1-1">TEST1</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="left size-3 responsive">
        <h3>
            <a class="txt-sm btn fast" href="#test2" data-ref="1-4" >TEST2</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="left size-3 responsive">
        <h3>
            <a class="txt-sm btn fast" href="#test3" data-ref="1-3">TEST3</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="left size-3 responsive">
        <h3>
            <a class="txt-sm btn fast" href="#test4" data-ref="1-6">TEST4</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap large">
     <div class="left size-3 responsive" data-tab="1-1">
          <div class="column">
               <div class="row-dark">
                    <p class="txt-xl">Package <b>1</b></p>
               </div>
               <div class="row-light">
                    <p class="txt-xs">test</p>
               </div>
               <div class="row-dark">
                    <p class="txt-xs">-</p>
               </div>
               <div class="row-light">
                    <p class="txt-xs">-</p>
               </div>
               <div class="row-dark">
                    <p class="txt-xs"><b>3000</b>  *</p>
               </div>
               <div class="row-light">
                    <a class="button border fast" href="/1">Start </a>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript to make the change on the scrolling menu. I want it to be white from the begging of the part A until the end of part A. Before and after that, i should be black.

As you can see, $startchange is the begging of part A and $endchange is the beginning of part B. 
This loop should make the color changement :

if((scroll_start > offset.top-menuSize) && (scroll_start < 1320))

And as you can see scroll_start is limited by 1320 but it's a fixed value...
If i try something like : var endchange = $('#testi').offset().top; It will returns 2700 because it considerate that the 4 options from part A are one below the other.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(window).on("load resize", function (event) {
        $("#menu").unstick().width("100%").height("auto").sticky();
    });
    var scroll_start = 0;
    var startchange = $('#pack');
    var endchange = $('#testi');
    var menuSize = $('#menu').height();
    var offset = startchange.offset();

    if (startchange.length){
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
            if((scroll_start > offset.top-menuSize) && (scroll_start < 1320)) 
            {
                $("#menu").css('background', '#eeeeee');
                $("#menu .content .wrap .txt-sm").css('color', '#222222');
                $("#menu .content .wrap .btn").css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00)');
                $("#menu .content .wrap .btn:hover").css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00)');
            } else {
                $("#menu").css('background', '#222222');
                $("#menu .content .wrap .txt-sm").css('color', '#ffffff');
                $("#menu .content .wrap .btn").css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00)');
                $("#menu .content .wrap .btn:hover").css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00)');
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

[image: Screenshot_PART_A_B]

Comment: Hi @Marc and welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you ,please ,add the JavaScript code? It's hard to understand what's wrong in the code without seeing it.

Comment: Hi @MoshFeu, thanks for your quick reply, i 've edited my post.

Comment: A. What is ` offset.top-menuSize`? B. I can't see element with `id` "pack" in `var startchange = $('#pack');`. Is there working demo (public URL or fiddle (using http://jsbin.com/ or similiar)) for this situation? I believe that if I can see this in action it will be easier to help.